# "You have a good pronunciation." vs "You have good pronunciation."

Tags: indefinite-article

As I understand, it's needed to use article "a" in this sentence, but I saw examples where it's not used. Why? Is it mistake or it is possible to use both variants?

> You have **a** good pronunciation.

Comment: *Why* do you think "it's needed"? In most contexts, we *wouldn't* include the article when talking about someone's pronunciation. And on the rare occasions where it might be appropriate (because we're talking about ***the*** pronunciation of ***a*** specific word) we'd more likely say ***You pronounce it well***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mostly want `You have good pronunciation`, meaning that generally your pronunciation is good.

If you are talking about pronunciation of a specific word and there are multiple acceptable pronunciations of it then you could use `a good pronunciation` but that would be more unusual.

Answer (score 2):

"Pronunciation" can be countable or uncountable.

It is uncountable if it means the sounds made when speaking a language or saying a word
"her pronunciation is good", "you have good pronunciation".

It is countable when it means a particular way of pronouncing a word or a language: "OED include different pronunciations for the same word"